# Python Errors " player instance has no attribute 'player_pos' " and "Parameter Value is not used"

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing, instance

I need help with my code. I am getting this error player " instance has no attribute 'player_pos' " along with " Parameter value is not used". I am confused about why my code is not working...

```
playerpos[0] = player1.player_move(player_pos[0]) #This is in the main file


# The class is in another file. The main ("game") file is importing the class("player") file.
class player:

    def __init__(self, color, size, speed):

        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.speed = speed

    def draw_player(self, screen, player_pos):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (player_pos[0], player_pos[1], self.size, self.size))

    def player_move(self, player_pos):   **<---- Error Here**
        # When calling this function, make sure it is set equal to player position's "x" value
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.player_pos -= self.speed
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.player_pos += self.speed
        return self.player_pos
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more information for people to be able to help you. The full error and all the code in which you instantiate player1 might reveal the issue. From what you have provided everything looks OK so I think the issue might be elsewhere.

Comment: I fixed it. I needed to remove "self.player_pos" and change it to just "player_pos"